# Progressive Web App - can it show a map using an offline Mapsforge .map file?

Tags: html, progressive-web-apps

Showing an offline map using 1 Mapsforge OSM map file is only possible in a HTML5 webapp using commercial tools like Mapbox. There are simply no free tools to do so, as you can read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43743097/showing-an-offline-osm-map-file-suggestion-an-mb-tiles-file-with-js-library).

Is it possible to show an offline Mapsforge OSM map in an **Progressive Web App**? That would really be great.

**Why an offline Mapsforge file**? It is a free and good OSM map. It is available as 1 file per (great) area, so not a huge bunch of small files in a x/y/z folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After scanning solutions, I think there is a better alternative for accessing offline OSM maps via mapsforge. The solution is for caching OSM map requests.  Using that approach you don't need to pre-load the mapsforge data. You just browse the area. An alternative is to start a 'seed' in order to pre-fetch lower levels of OSM data.

Caching map requests are possible in a number of ways. As a first introduction, I refer to [a recommendation for storing data offline](https://medium.com/dev-channel/offline-storage-for-progressive-web-apps-70d52695513c):

For URL addressable resources, use the Cache API (part of Service Worker). For all other data, use IndexedDB (with a Promises wrapper).

Comment: Hi, when you said "seed" what are you talking exactly? Thanks!

Comment: 'Seed' means that you retrieve all underlying map levels. If you just get a map on exactly 1 level, say 17, and you go offline, then you cannot zoom in to lower levels. You did not retrieve the levels 18, 19, etc.